# VS2017 Error when trying to build ASP.NET MVC 5 App. Roslyn\bin\csc.exe is denied

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2017, roslyn

It would seem its a known issue and I have followed the advice of several forums to downgrade my `Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform` to 1.0.5 And my `Microsoft.Net.Compilers` to 2.1.0. This fixed the issue for a few days but now, out of nowhere, it has returned. I get the following error when I try to build my project:

> D:\VS 17 Projects\ReminderNotes\ReminderNotes\bin\roslyn\csc.exe". Access to the path 'D:\VS 17 Projects\ReminderNotes\ReminderNotes\bin\roslyn\csc.exe' is denied.

And:

> D:\VS 17 Projects\ReminderNotes\ReminderNotes\bin\roslyn\VBCSCompiler.exe". Access to the path 'D:\VS 17 Projects\ReminderNotes\ReminderNotes\bin\roslyn\VBCSCompiler.exe' is denied.

[image: Screen shot of the error when i debug]

Any ideas?

Comment: shutdown VS and then kill any instances of VBCSCompiler.exe running

Comment: I have tried that. I couldnt find any instances of VBCS running in task manager. Is there anywhere else to look?

Comment: this is the exact issue I have run into before with VS 2017 and killing any process it started is what you want todo.  simply restarting VS isn't enough.  kill IISExpress OR restart IIS, it appears you are using IISExpress so make sure its gone, right clicking on system tray to kill isn't the way to go, use task manager.  IF you cannot get that to work then restart your machine that will most definitely kill anything, last resort I know

Comment: In some ways its good to hear its a “common” problem. I’ll try restarting the computer in the morning (its night here) and post back. I really hope that works though as solutions go its pretty annoying to have to restart your machine everytime this issue pops up. There must be some cause and effect going on which means there must be a solution to the problem.

Comment: I experience it when I am debugging two apps at once using the same instance of VS.  rather annoying AND I have found that no one has reported this bug.  I will debug a web project and a console app that access the controllers from that web project.  it seems the web project doesn't know how to clean itself up

Comment: Are u running as admin?

Comment: So, I have booted up my computer and i still get the same error screen. Im not running as admin....